# How to add variables in mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to add `$query_bookname` and `$query_author` after `$_GET['category']`
How can I do that?
(The double and single quotation marks are confusing me a lot)

```
$query_bookname = "AND book_name LIKE '%".$_GET['book_name']."%' ";
$query_author = "AND author LIKE '%".$_GET['author']."%' ";

$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM book
    WHERE cate_name = '".$_GET['category']."' AND status = 1
");
```

Comment: Apart from SQLInjection , I think you are doing it the right way..

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this, but you need to address the weaknesses in your code (per Shankar Damodaran):

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM book
WHERE cate_name = '".$_GET['category']."' AND status = 1
$query_bookname
$query_author
");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM book
    WHERE cate_name = '".$_GET['category']." ".$query_author." ".$query_author." AND status = 1
");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM book
    WHERE cate_name = '".$_GET['category']."' AND status = 1
    $query_bookname 
    $query_author
");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book
  WHERE cate_name = '".$_GET['category']."' AND ".$query_bookname.$query_bookname." status = 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP code:

```
$q="";
$q .= " AND book_name LIKE '%".$_GET['book_name']."%' ";
$q .= " AND author LIKE '%".$_GET['author']."%' ";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book WHERE cate_name = '".$_GET['category']."' AND status = 1 $q");
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation of this code please.

Answer (score -1):

```
$query_bookname = ''; $query_author = '';
if(isset($_GET['book_name']) && $_GET['book_name']!=''){
   $query_bookname = " AND book_name LIKE '%".$_GET['book_name']."%' ";
}
if(isset($_GET['author']) && $_GET['author']!=''){
$query_author = " AND author LIKE '%".$_GET['author']."%' ";
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book   WHERE cate_name = '".$_GET['category']."'  $query_bookname  $query_author AND status = 1");
```